# Filter card text using a custom search term

Tags: trello, trello-cards

In my Trello board I need to filter my cards using a search term like `14.2` (like a year-version number); when I set a filter like that the cards are not filtered in the correct way.

Is the `.` a special char? How can I filter my cards using `14.2`?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to accomplish this would be to use the dash (-) instead of the dot. (.)  Add something like 14-2 to the card name title. (not in the description)

Card labels are the best way to filter for cards and there are 6 labels available. Labels add color bars to your cards too. Use the above method if you need more than 6 label filters.